# Fastest way to convert all elements of a numpy array to string

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a array named X of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`  that prints elements in the following format.

`[[b'0' b'0']]` and i want to convert each of the element inside the array to a string. I am wondering what is the fastest possible way to do this in python?

The one obvious way is to loop through the array and convert each element at a time to a string and store it in a new array but that seems slow to me and i feel python may have faster way to do this. I have arrays that are of huge size so i think speed plays a huge role.

Comment: You can use [`ndarray.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) like so: `X.astype(str)`

Comment: `arr.astype(str)`?

Comment: Thank you! @Alex I would love to accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: `b'0'` js a string, a bytestring.  Look at `X.dtype`; it should be something like `S1`.  Strings without the `b` are unicode, with a `U_` dtype.